# Is there a way to output the long date from javascript datapicker

Tags: javascript, html, date, datepicker

In this date-picker, after selecting a date from the calendar, the selected date is outputted in the format dd-mm-yy, is there a way to output the date in the long format(Monday 21 February 2022.) There source of this date-picker is: https://code-boxx.com/simple-datepicker-pure-javascript-css/#sec-download

```
  // CHOOSE A DATE
  pick : (id, day) => {
    // (C1) GET MONTH YEAR
    let inst = picker.instances[id],
        month = inst.hMonth.value,
        year = inst.hYear.value;

    // FORMAT & SET SELECTED DAY (DD-MM-YYYY)
    if (+month<10) { month = "0" + month; }
    if (+day<10) { day = "0" + day; }
    inst.target.value = `${day}-${month}-${year}`;

   //  POPUP ONLY - CLOSE
  if (inst.container === undefined) {
    inst.hWrap.classList.remove("show");
  }
    // CALL ON PICK IF DEFINED
    if (inst.onpick) { inst.onpick(); }
  }
};
```

Comment: The easiest way is to use a library like https://date-fns.org/, https://github.com/moment/luxon#readme, or https://day.js.org/.

Comment: There is probably a way in your date picker to directly get the date in the format you prefer. but as you do not indicate which date picker you are using we cannot tell you . Wich one is it ? https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=datepicker&type=Repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date picker value will be in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`, you can parse this (using [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and pass the year, month and day to the Date() constructor.

We can then use [`Date.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to output the correct format:

```js
function dateChanged() {
    const dt = getDatePickerDate('date-input');
    const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = dt.toLocaleDateString([], options);
}

function getDatePickerDate(elementId) {
    const value = document.getElementById(elementId).value
    const [year, month, day] = value.split('-');
    return new Date(year, month - 1, day);
}
```

```html
<input id='date-input' type="date" value="2022-02-21" onchange='dateChanged()'>
<p id='output'></p>
```